# Are LDR Hotfixes for .Net cumulative?

Tags: c#, runtime, clr

I suspect that we are encountering a problem that is addressed by this hotfix: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2640103

I am trying to figure out whether a KB titled" "hotfix rollup for the .Net Framework 4 June 2013 includes the fix I am after: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2828843

Now, I'm tempted to say "well, duh, it's a rollup.".  BUT, If you scroll down to the list of "Issues that this hotfix rollup resolves", my fix is not listed. In fact only 7 items are listed.  So does that mean that the rollup only addresses those 7 issues?

I read about how to decode GDR vs. LDR version numbers here: http://blogs.technet.com/b/mrsnrub/archive/2009/05/14/gdr-qfe-ldr-wth.aspx and here: http://blogs.technet.com/b/mrsnrub/archive/2010/07/14/gdr-amp-ldr-the-next-generation.aspx (interesting reading, by the way).

And found this listing of all .Net 4.0 releases: 
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dougste/archive/2011/09/30/version-history-of-the-clr-4-0.aspx

But, I still can't answer my question.  It boils down to:
The June 2013 Rollup is LDR branch 2008.
The hotfix I am looking is in LDR branch 526 (which, according to the revision history has never been in a GDR.

Let's make this more complicated.  The GDR version of 4.0 that I have installed is newer than the LDR hotfix that I need, so should I deploy the 526 LDR, or will the 2008 LDR have the fix that I need?

Comment: Is your problem easily reproducible? If so, just apply 2008 LDR to a test environment and try to reproduce the issue. Not sure why you need to do more than that.

Comment: It's not easily reproducible.  It relates to a memory corruption problem in mixed mode applications.

Comment: If it's not reproducible, how will you know if any of the possible hotfixes or rollups fix your issue?

Comment: It's not easily reproducible, but we do have good statistics on frequency -- The operation that is erring fails about 100 times per day -- about 3 percent of time.  We host it, so we control the rollout. If we release the hotfix, we should within a day or so if it impacted the error.

Comment: If you really want an exact answer to this, I'm afraid you will likely need to open a support case with Microsoft. Otherwise trial and error is your only way.